# How to get PreSaveAction to work in a default NewForm.aspx - SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a default newform.aspx and i did add a PreSave Action function like so:
I edited the default NewForm.aspx and i added my js just under the

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">



  function PreSaveAction(){
        //Field was disabled so enabled it 
        $("input[Title='Location']").attr("disabled","");

        return true;    
        }
```

**Its inside a script just didn't add it**

But when i click the save button that field doesn't insert.
Any ideas.Can i do this in a default NewForm.aspx page?

Comment: Can someone guide me on this.I reid it with a custom list with also no luck.
Cheers

Comment: Is this your actual code? If not, please edit your question with the real code. If so, as written, your javascript code should appear as plain text on your page because it is not inside script tags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rich.Basically with SP 2010 i needed to use PreSaveItems not PreSaveAction.
The other question i need to ask is what do i need to do in PreSaveItems if i need to disable a textbox when the page is loaded and enable it on PreSaveItems and then Disable it back again.